# Use doc_count as cumulative count

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I'm currently attempting to generate graphs from data collected in Elastic Search. Every time an user is generated, I insert a record in ES, having the following (example) data:

```json
{
  "country": "US",
  "id": "79ca9523dcd62420030de12b75e08bb7",
  "createdAt": "1450912898"
}
```

ID is a hash of the User ID, so that the User ID can not be determined from the ID stored in ES, for privacy reasons.

The type mapping in the ES index is as following:

```
{
  "user": {
    "_timestamp": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "country": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_second"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, to get a graph of users per day, I have the following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "type": {
      "value": "user"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "createdAt",
        "interval": "day"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me a nice result such as this (for the result I set the interval to minute to give you a slight idea of what the problem is):

```
[{
  "key_as_string": "1450909920",
  "key": 1450909920000,
  "doc_count": 8
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450909980",
  "key": 1450909980000,
  "doc_count": 2
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910040",
  "key": 1450910040000,
  "doc_count": 5
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910100",
  "key": 1450910100000,
  "doc_count": 8
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910160",
  "key": 1450910160000,
  "doc_count": 4
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910220",
  "key": 1450910220000,
  "doc_count": 3
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910280",
  "key": 1450910280000,
  "doc_count": 6
}]
```

I'd like to use the `doc_count` to generate a cumulative graph, so that I can see the growth of my userbase, instead of the amount of accounts made per day. Despite searching on the internet, I can not find a single answer that seems to be related to my question. Most answers I find are directing me to the [Cumulative Sum Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation.html) page, but the example given there will give you a cumulative sum of all results captured in a single bucket. I'd like a cumulative sum of all bucket totals.

Comment: So, following your example the `doc_count` for `"key_as_string": "1450909980"` should be 8 (previous doc_count) + 2?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be stored in doc_count, but yes.

Comment: This sounds more like something that can be done client-side. I mean, the important bits of info are there, the resulting set of data just needs to be tuned. Also, depending on how you plan on using these results (UI graph for example), the "cumulative" thing might be dealt with in the graph itself.

Comment: I was quite sure that ES would be able to support something along these lines, as it is also able to do the cumulative sum of a field within the documents, then why not a cumulative sum of the bucket content's count?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right path with the [cumulative sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation.html) and you can definitely use it. You just need to use the special [`_count` bucket path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#_special_paths) and that will do the job you expect.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "type": {
      "value": "user"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "createdAt",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "cumulative": {
          "cumulative_sum": {
            "buckets_path": "_count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results will look like this:

```
[{
  "key_as_string": "1450909920",
  "key": 1450909920000,
  "doc_count": 8,
  "cumulative": {"value": 8}
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450909980",
  "key": 1450909980000,
  "doc_count": 2,
  "cumulative": {"value": 10}
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910040",
  "key": 1450910040000,
  "doc_count": 5,
  "cumulative": {"value": 15}
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910100",
  "key": 1450910100000,
  "doc_count": 8,
  "cumulative": {"value": 23}
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910160",
  "key": 1450910160000,
  "doc_count": 4,
  "cumulative": {"value": 27}
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910220",
  "key": 1450910220000,
  "doc_count": 3,
  "cumulative": {"value": 30}
},
{
  "key_as_string": "1450910280",
  "key": 1450910280000,
  "doc_count": 6,
  "cumulative": {"value": 36}
}]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I attempted to use `doc_count`, `count`, but did not think about `_count`